# Fieldset implementation in Symfony forms

Tags: php, forms, symfony1, fieldset

on the project I am writing with Symfony, there will be fieldsets in forms very often, so I would like to create a mechanism so that I can group fields by fieldsets and still use the __toString() method of my forms.
On [this page](http://www.symfony-project.org/forms/1_4/en/A-Widgets), I read about the sfWidgetFormSchema, and how it could be considered as a widget, which enables to nest fields.
So here is what I did:
I created nested fields:

```
   $this->setWidgets(array(
      'customer'    => new sfWidgetFormSchema(array(
        'customer_name'      => new sfWidgetFormInputText(),
        'customer_email'     => new sfWidgetFormInputText(array())
      )),
      'library'     => new sfWidgetFormSchema(array(
        'library_name'      => new sfWidgetFormInputText(),
        'library_address'   => new sfWidgetFormInputText(),
        'library_city'      => new sfWidgetFormInputText(),
        'library_postcode'  => new sfWidgetFormInputText(),
        'library_website'   => new sfWidgetFormInputText()
      )),
      'message'     => new sfWidgetFormTextarea(array(),array( "cols" => 50, "rows" => 10 )),
    ));
```

Then I created a fieldsetFormSchemaFormatter class, which basically wraps fields in  tags, and associated it with the sfWidgetFormSchema fields:

```
foreach (array('customer', 'library') as $fieldset)
    {
      $this->widgetSchema[$fieldset]->addFormFormatter('tableless',
        new tableLessFormSchemaFormatter($this->widgetSchema['customer']));
      $this->widgetSchema[$fieldset]->setFormFormatterName('tableless');
      $this->widgetSchema[$fieldset]->setNameFormat('%s');
    }
    $this->widgetSchema->addFormFormatter('fieldset',
      new FieldsetFormSchemaFormatter($this->widgetSchema,
        'TableLessFormSchemaFormatter'));
    $this->widgetSchema->setFormFormatterName('fieldset');
```

And it just worked fine, I got my fieldset form. The problem I have is with validation, which is not at all described on the page I linked sooner in this question. The error messages appear on top of the form for all fields but the "message" field, which has an error message right after it. I don't think I'm gonna be able to get the error messages to display right after the rows and still use the echo $form construct without coding something ugly, so I think I'm gonna go with another implementation.
I think that sfWidgetFormSchema widgets are meant to build interdependant fields, which would have global validation rules.

How would you implement this fieldset functionality?

Comment: Could you just use verbose templates instead and add the fieldsets manually?  Not super elegant but would work, just depends how many forms you have.

Comment: @Luke: Yes I could, but I'd like not to. I'm currently implementing the fieldset functionality in a class inheriting from sfWidgetFormSchema (I'm going to override the render() method). Since I have many forms in many projects, I think it is worth it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what I have come up with after some research, it seems to work fine, but the positions mechanism is not used anymore when rendering. I wonder if this can be problematic.

```
<?php
class UcWidgetFormSchema extends sfWidgetFormSchema
{
  /**
   * An associative array with all the fieldsets
   * <code>
   *   array(
   *    "fieldset1" => array("fieldName1", "fieldName2"),
   *    "fieldset2" => array("fieldName3", "fieldName4"),
   *   )
   * </code>
   *
   * @var array
   */
  private $fieldsets;

  /**
   * A fieldset-compatible constructor.
   *
   * @param mixed $fields     Initial fields. Values can be given this way:
   * <code>
   *  array(
   *    "fieldset1" => array(
   *      "field1" => $widget1,
   *      "field2" => $widget2
   *    )
   *    "fieldset1" => array(
   *      "field3" => $widget3,
   *      "field4" => $widget4,
   *      "field5" => $widget5
   *    )
   *    "message" => $widget6
   *  )
   * </code>
   * @param array $options    An array of options
   * @param array $attributes An array of default HTML attributes
   * @param array $labels     An array of HTML labels
   * @param array $helps      An array of help texts
   */
  public function __construct($fields = null, $options = array(),
    $attributes = array(), $labels = array(), $helps = array())
  {
    $this->addOption('name_format', '%s');
    $this->addOption('form_formatter', null);

    parent::__construct($options, $attributes);

    if (is_array($fields))
    {
      $fieldsets = array();
      foreach ($fields as $name => $value)
      {
        if (is_array($value))
        {
          $fieldsets[$name] = array_keys($value);
          foreach ($value as $valueName=> $valueWidget)
          {
            $this[$valueName] = $valueWidget;
          }
        }
        else
        {
          $this[$name] = $value;
        }
      }
      $this->setFieldsets($fieldsets);
    }
    else if (null !== $fields)
    {
      throw new InvalidArgumentException('sfWidgetFormSchema constructor takes an array of sfWidget objects.');
    }

    $this->setLabels($labels);
    $this->helps = $helps;
  }

  /**
   * Setter for the fieldsets
   *
   * @param array $fieldsets an associative array
   *
   * @return null
   */
  public function setFieldsets(array $fieldsets)
  {
    $fieldNames = array();
    foreach ($fieldsets as $fieldset => $fieldsetFieldNames)
    {
      $fieldNames = array_merge($fieldNames, $fieldsetFieldNames);
    }
    $availableFieldsNames =  array_keys($this->getFields());
    if ($diff = array_diff(array_unique($fieldNames), $fieldNames))
    {
      throw new InvalidArgumentException(
        'A field can only be used once in all fieldset. These do not: ' .
        implode(', ', $diff));
    }

    if ($diff = array_diff($fieldNames, $availableFieldsNames))
    {
      throw new InvalidArgumentException(
        'Widget schema does not include the following field(s): ' .
        implode(', ', $diff));
    }
    $this->fieldsets = $fieldsets;
  }

  public function render($name, $values = array(), $attributes = array(), $errors = array())
  {
    if(!$this->getFormFormatter() instanceof FieldsettedFormFormatterInterface )
    {
      throw new LogicException('The formatter you are using must implement FieldsettedFormFormatterInterface');
    }

    if (null === $values)
    {
      $values = array();
    }

    if (!is_array($values) && !$values instanceof ArrayAccess)
    {
      throw new InvalidArgumentException('You must pass an array of values to render a widget schema');
    }

    $formFormat = $this->getFormFormatter();


    $groups       = array();
    $hiddenRows   = array();
    $errorRows    = array();
    $lonelyFields = $this->getPositions();
    $lonelyRows   = array();

    // render each field
    foreach ($this->fieldsets as $fieldset => $fieldNames)
    {
      $rows = array();
      foreach ($fieldNames as $name)
      {
        $lonelyFields     = array_diff($lonelyFields, array($name));
        $widget           = $this[$name];
        $value            = isset($values[$name]) ? $values[$name] : null;
        $error            = isset($errors[$name]) ? $errors[$name] : array();
        $widgetAttributes = isset($attributes[$name]) ? $attributes[$name] : array();

        if ($widget instanceof sfWidgetForm && $widget->isHidden())
        {
          $hiddenRows[] = $this->renderField($name, $value, $widgetAttributes);
        }
        else
        {
          $field = $this->renderField($name, $value, $widgetAttributes, $error);

          // don't add a label tag and errors if we embed a form schema
          $label = $widget instanceof sfWidgetFormSchema ?
            $this->getFormFormatter()->generateLabelName($name) :
            $this->getFormFormatter()->generateLabel($name);
          $error = $widget instanceof sfWidgetFormSchema ? array() : $error;

          $rows[] = $formFormat->formatRow($label, $field, $error,
            $this->getHelp($name));
        }
        $groups[$fieldset] = $rows;
      }
    }

    foreach ($lonelyFields as $name)
    {
      $widget           = $this[$name];
      $value            = isset($values[$name]) ? $values[$name] : null;
      $error            = isset($errors[$name]) ? $errors[$name] : array();
      $widgetAttributes = isset($attributes[$name]) ? $attributes[$name] : array();

      if ($widget instanceof sfWidgetForm && $widget->isHidden())
      {
        $hiddenRows[] = $this->renderField($name, $value, $widgetAttributes);
      }
      else
      {
        $field = $this->renderField($name, $value, $widgetAttributes, $error);

        // don't add a label tag and errors if we embed a form schema
        $label = $widget instanceof sfWidgetFormSchema ?
          $this->getFormFormatter()->generateLabelName($name) :
          $this->getFormFormatter()->generateLabel($name);
        $error = $widget instanceof sfWidgetFormSchema ? array() : $error;

        $lonelyRows[] = strtr($formFormat
          ->formatRow($label, $field, $error, $this->getHelp($name)),
          array('%hidden_fields%' => ''));
      }
    }

    $html = '';

    if ($groups)
    {
      // insert hidden fields in the last row
      $i        = 0;
      $maxGroup = count($groups);
      foreach ($groups as $fieldset => $group)
      {

        for ($j = 0, $max = count($group); $j < $max; $j++)
        {
          $group[$j] = strtr($group[$j], array('%hidden_fields%' =>
            (($i == $maxGroup -1) && $j == $max - 1) ?
              implode("\n", $hiddenRows) : ''));
        }

        $html .= $this->getFormFormatter()
          ->formatFieldSet($fieldset, implode('', $group));
        $i++;
      }
    }
    else
    {
      // only hidden fields
      $lonelyRows[] = implode("\n", $hiddenRows);
    }
    $html .= implode('', $lonelyRows);

    return $this->getFormFormatter()
      ->formatErrorRow($this->getGlobalErrors($errors)) . $html;
  }
}
```

Here is the interface your formatter must implement if you want to use it:

```
interface FieldsettedFormFormatterInterface
{
  /**
   * This method will be used to render a fieldset
   *
   * @param string $name    the name of the widget
   * @param string $widgets the widgets html
   *
   * @return string the html for the fieldset
   */
  public function formatFieldset($name, $widgets);
}
```